# What should i do for master page logic in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I m new in mvc. I had a web forms application and there was a masterpage of every page.

there was a virtual function in master page template and every page's page_load i was overriding it.

now i have mvc pattern in my project. where exactly should i put all these business in my project.

Answer (score 2):

there are special views that can be used in MVC(assuming your are using razor).

There views are [_viewstart](http://jittuu.com/2011/10/28/ViewStart-in-MVC-3/) and [_layout](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)(though can be named anything else).
so basically a _layout.cshtml view in a specific controller's views folder can work as a master page for the views existing in the same folder and a _layout.cshtml view in the shared folder can work as a master page for all the views present.

to specify to use a particular view as a masterpage use set the Layout variable inside the view. for ex `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml";`

Comment: so this is so logical. except for this what should i do for some codefile checks? for example in every page i want to check the user name is cerq

Comment: Ideally you should not CHECK the username inside the view do it in controller. but still if you want to do it. you can do it inside of _viewstart

Comment: of course i want to CHECK in controller. but writing in every action is not the way i want also i dont know that is the true way. so i have asked this question

Answer (score 1):

Normally Master Pages goes in Shared folder in Views Folder.

I would recommend if you have multiple masterpages, try to minimize number for the same.

Make a parent Masterpage which should be called on all pages.

For using mutiple masterpages you can do something like this

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            this.MasterPageFile = "~/Views/Shared/Site2.Master";
        }
        else
        {
            this.MasterPageFile = "~/Views/Shared/Site.Master";
        }
    }
```

Also you can use
ViewMasterPage.MasterPageFile inbuilt class